dropdownbox did not change the value but it also correctly store in setState i have print for console how fix the issue
 DropdownButton<String>(
                                value: _selectedFilterOption,
                                icon: const Icon(Icons.filter_alt),
                                onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    _selectedFilterOption = newValue!;
                                    debugPrint(
                                        "selected filter option: $_selectedFilterOption");

                                    // Reset other filter options when switching to a new filter
                                    if (_selectedFilterOption !=
                                        AppLocalizations.of(context)!.gender) {
                                      _selectedGender = 'All';
                                    }
                                    if (_selectedFilterOption !=
                                        AppLocalizations.of(context)!
                                            .location) {
                                      _selectedLocation = 'All';
                                    }
                                    if (_selectedFilterOption !=
                                        AppLocalizations.of(context)!
                                            .priority) {
                                      _selectedPriority = 'All';
                                    }
                                  });
                                  debugPrint(
                                      "setselected value confirm : $_selectedFilterOption");

                                  // Fetch data based on the selected filter option
                                  fetchFilderOptionData();
                                },
                                items: <String>[
                                  AppLocalizations.of(context)!.filter_by,
                                  AppLocalizations.of(context)!.gender,
                                  AppLocalizations.of(context)!.location,
                                  AppLocalizations.of(context)!.priority,
                                ].map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                                  return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                    value: value,
                                    child: Text(value),
                                  );
                                }).toList(),
                              ),


how to fix the issue


Does the dropdown menu reflect the change? What is printed exactly? I see two print statements. Can you post whats printed?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
